# How to force MERGE statement with DELETE to use index seek?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, merge, seek

I have made MS SQL 2014 database for my Facebook app that works with friends. I am keeping friends for all my users in DB and updating them from Facebook on app start. For that I used MERGE statement (table variable @FriendUserIds contains list of friends' IDs; table UserFriends has clustered primary key (UserId, FriendUserId)):

```
MERGE UserFriends
    USING (
        SELECT
                UserId
            FROM @FriendUserIds
    ) AS source (FriendUserId)
        ON UserFriends.UserId = @UserId
            AND UserFriends.FriendUserId = source.FriendUserId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (UserId, FriendUserId)
            VALUES (@UserId, source.FriendUserId)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
        AND UserFriends.UserId = @UserId
        THEN DELETE;
```

Problem is that query optimizer does not recognize that it can use INDEX SEEK on UserFriends. It uses SCAN instead and I do not know about a way to force SEEK.
For now I circumvented the problem by splitting operation into two queries (MERGE for adding new friends and DELETE for deleting no longer friends), which is still way faster than single MERGE statement (MERGE without DELETE statement uses SEEK):

```
DELETE
    FROM UserFriends
    WHERE UserFriends.UserId = @UserId
        AND UserFriends.FriendUserId NOT IN (
            SELECT
                    UF.UserId
                FROM @FriendUserIds UF
        )

MERGE UserFriends
    USING (
        SELECT
                UserId
            FROM @FriendUserIds
    ) AS source (FriendUserId)
        ON UserFriends.UserId = @UserId
            AND UserFriends.FriendUserId = source.FriendUserId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (UserId, FriendUserId)
            VALUES (@UserId, source.FriendUserId);
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify a MERGE hint (`MERGE UserFriends WITH(INDEX(<index to seek>)) ...` or `MERGE UserFriends WITH(FORCESEEK(<index to seek>)) ...`?

Comment: I tried FORCESEEK. Query will fail - optimizer is not able to find usable index.

Comment: Try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of your merge statement. SQL optimizer will use the first @UserId you specified when you first ran it to generate cached plan. Option (Recompile) will use actual value to generate the plan, note this has a small overhead of a recompile every time the statement is run.

Comment: I tried multiple variations with forcing index, forcing seek and OPTION(RECOMPILE). Since optimizer already uses index I want it to use (clustered primary key) forcing it changes nothing. Forcing it to SEEK makes it fail. RECOMPILE changes nothing.

Looks to me like either there need to be change in syntax to let oprimizer know that it is that kind of query or SQL server just does not have the option implemented.

Comment: Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: I've had lots of problems with `MERGE` and used your exact solution - split into different statements. When researching a proper solution I always come back to this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1465931-391-2.aspx. It actual goes through a whole lot of standard query optimisation approaches like checking actual vs estimated query plan. So I sugegst the first thing you do is collect actual query plans for all of the cases and see if anything stands out - for example very different cardinality estimates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a Common Table Expression (CTE) as your "target":

```
;WITH UserFriends_CTE
     AS (SELECT [UserID],
                [FriendUserID]
         FROM   [UserFriends]
         WHERE  [UserID] = @UserId)
MERGE UserFriends_CTE
USING (SELECT [UserId]
       FROM   @FriendUserIds) AS source ([FriendUserId])
ON UserFriends_CTE.[UserId] = @UserId
   AND UserFriends_CTE.[FriendUserId] = source.[FriendUserId]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT ([UserId],
          [FriendUserId])
  VALUES (@UserId,
          source.[FriendUserId])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  DELETE;
```

`MERGE` statements often perform worse than splitting into multiple statements, and [there are a few known problems with MERGE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement). Using a CTE *can* cause issues [according to Paul White in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30633/merge-a-subset-of-the-target-table), so test it.

If you do use a split version, here's how I would implement it:

```
DELETE uf
FROM   [UserFriends] uf
WHERE  uf.[UserId] = @UserId
       AND NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT 1
                FROM   @FriendUserIds fu
                WHERE  uf.[FriendUserId] = fu.[FriendUserId]);

INSERT INTO [UserFriends]
            ([UserId],
             [FriendUserId])
SELECT @UserId,
       fu.[FriendUserId]
FROM   @FriendUserIds fu
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
            FROM   [UserFriends] uf
            WHERE  fu.[FriendUserId] = uf.[FriendUserId]
                   AND uf.[UserId] = @UserId);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link to the Paul White's answer. I learned something new today. It seems that CTE doesn't guarantee correct results with `MERGE`, but only updating through the view does. Or, having a separate `DELETE` statement, of course.

Comment: In `MERGE` statement, since you have set alias for `UserFriends_CTE` (`MERGE UserFriends_CTE AS target`) you need to use `target` instead later in the code. To 2 query solution, solution in my question (with `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`) is faster. Apart from that, your solution with CTE works perfectly, I was starting to think it can't be done :). Bounty is yours.

Answer (score 0):

First obvious variant is to use two explicit statements: `DELETE` and `INSERT`. You never update existing rows, so you can use a traditional `INSERT` instead of `MERGE`.

```
DELETE FROM UserFriends
WHERE 
    UserFriends.UserId = @UserId
    AND UserFriends.FriendUserId NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT UF.UserId
        FROM @FriendUserIds AS UF
    )
;

INSERT INTO UserFriends(UserId, FriendUserId)
SELECT @UserId, UF.UserId
FROM @FriendUserIds AS UF
WHERE
    UF.UserId NOT IN
    (
        SELECT UserFriends.FriendUserId
        FROM UserFriends
        WHERE UserFriends.UserId = @UserId
    )
;
```

Wrap it in transaction and `TRY ... CATCH` with proper error handling.

---

Second variant is to try to keep single `MERGE`, but make sure that table variable has primary key/clustered unique index. It may help optimizer.

The definition of the table type would look something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserIdsTableType] AS TABLE
(
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
))
```

---

Third variant is to use a #temp table instead of table variable again with primary key/clustered unique index. It may help optimizer further, because cardinality estimates for table variables is not the same as for normal or temp tables. It is usually 1, i.e. optimizer doesn't know how many rows are in the table variable and assumes that it is always 1 row. For temp tables it should know the row count.

---

In fact, third variant makes sense even if you use two explicit `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements instead of single `MERGE`.

It would be interesting to see actual execution plan for `MERGE` using temp table vs. actual plan for the two separate statements using temp table. Theoretically single `MERGE` could be faster, because it may have to join two tables only once.

Comment: Hey @vladimir would you preferred not exists if inner query columns 
are NULLABLE

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma, The question says that table UserFriends has clustered primary key `(UserId, FriendUserId)`, so both `UserId` and `FriendUserId` must be NOT NULL. Most likely, if you rewrite the query and use `EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`, optimizer would generate the same execution plan anyway.

Comment: jumped on your answer without reading the question fully,
you are spot on

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov Good point with the `INSERT` instead of `MERGE`. I used `MERGE` in the test so I can confirm that the `DELETE` is the part causing the scan.

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov `UserIds` is clustered, with `PRIMARY KEY` on UserId. About #temp table, I use table variable since it is parameter of the stored procedure. I can't really replace it with #temp table (I tried it just to see and it didn't change the diagram, but did change some stats by negligible amount).

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov I did one more test to compare `DELETE` + `INSERT` with `DELETE` + `MERGE` and result surprised me. `DELETE` + `MERGE` was faster since it used Left Outer Join and `INSERT` used Left Anti Semi Join and Eager Spool. I tested both your `INSERT` and my variant with `EXCEPT` statement (with same result).

Comment: @JozefBabinsky, did you try to define the type for the table variable with the clustered primary key? (I added example to the answer) Can you share the full XML of the **actual** execution plan of the single `MERGE` statement? It would be better if you used [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) for this (save `sqlplan`). You can use pastebin.com to share the long XML text.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov As I wrote in previous comment ;) yes, there is clustered primary key defined for the table variable type. Actual Execution Plan for the single `MERGE` statement: http://pastebin.com/PmhHvVgM

Comment: @JozefBabinsky, sorry, I misunderstood that comment. Does the table `UserFriends` really has only 3115 rows? If yes, then the plan looks pretty good to me. With such low row count optimizer decides that it is faster to scan the whole index instead of seeking. It **is** a bit strange that optimizer doesn't seek using `@UserId`. It should not hurt even with low row count. Are you sure that `PK_Friends` is defined with `UserId` first, like this: `(UserId,FriendUserId)`, not `(FriendUserId,UserId)`?

Comment: @JozefBabinsky, ... On a second thought, I realized that I don't really understand what is going on in this query. I don't understand why the query affects 0 rows in the end with 14 rows in `@UserIds` and 3115 rows in `UserFriends`. Shouldn't it delete at least 3101 rows from `UserFriends`? You'd better edit the question and include the link to the execution plan there. Maybe someone else would explain what is going on.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov It is just test db, live there is much more rows. Anyways, if it would use seek instead of scan, the query would be more than 5x faster (when I compare it to how it is executed in `DELETE` + `MERGE` solution) even with only 3k rows. Index `PK_Friends`: I am sure, otherwise the 2 query solution would not seek either.
There is no rows updated in the plan since the rows in the `UserFriends` table are the same as the rows in the input table variable.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov And it only affects rows with one `UserId`, other rows in the table are friends of another users and those are ignored thanks to `ON UserFriends.UserId = @UserId` and `AND UserFriends.UserId = @UserId`